# Module passport-oauth2 in nodej.js: extra parameters to be included in the authorization request

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0

I have a problem with implementing an Oauth2 authentication in node.js application where I need to add one extra parameter in the authorization request, but the module simply ignores the "unknown" parameters.

My code is attached below. The parameter being ignored is `APIName`.

```
var OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy;

// load the auth variables
var configAuth = require('./auth');

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.use('ihealth', new OAuth2Strategy({
            authorizationURL: 'https://api.ihealthlabs.com:8443/OpenApiV2/OAuthv2/userauthorization/',
            tokenURL: 'https://api.ihealthlabs.com:8443/OpenApiV2/OAuthv2/userauthorization/',
            clientID: configAuth.iHealthAuth.clientID,
            clientSecret: configAuth.iHealthAuth.clientSecret,
            callbackURL: configAuth.iHealthAuth.callbackURL,
            APIName : 'OpenApiActivity'
        },
        function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            // ...

        }
    ));
};
```

The reason that I know `APIName` is being ignored, is that I see the URL in the browser:

```
https://api.ihealthlabs.com:8443/OpenApiV2/OAuthv2/userauthorization/?response_type=code&redirect_uri=SOMEREDIRECTURI&client_id=SOMECLIENTID
```

I am wondering how to enable adding extra parameters to the authorization request? Maybe by overriding the function `OAuth2Strategy.prototype.authorizationParams` in `node_modules/passport_oauth2/lib/strategy.js`, which looks like this in the donwloaded file:

```
/**
 * Return extra parameters to be included in the authorization request.
 *
 * Some OAuth 2.0 providers allow additional, non-standard parameters to be
 * included when requesting authorization.  Since these parameters are not
 * standardized by the OAuth 2.0 specification, OAuth 2.0-based authentication
 * strategies can overrride this function in order to populate these parameters
 * as required by the provider.
 *
 * @param {Object} options
 * @return {Object}
 * @api protected
 */
OAuth2Strategy.prototype.authorizationParams = function(options) {
  return {};
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override `OAuth2Strategy.prototype.authorizationParams` as follows

```
 var myStrategy = new OAuth2Strategy({
        authorizationURL: 'https://api.ihealthlabs.com:8443/OpenApiV2/OAuthv2/userauthorization/',
        tokenURL: 'https://api.ihealthlabs.com:8443/OpenApiV2/OAuthv2/userauthorization/',
        clientID: configAuth.iHealthAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.iHealthAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.iHealthAuth.callbackURL
    },
    function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        // ...
    });

    myStrategy.authorizationParams = function(options) {
      return {
        APIName : 'OpenApiActivity'
      };
    };

    passport.use('ihealth',myStrategy);
```

For Microsoft ADFS OAuth 2, this can be used to add the required `source` parameter; if one wants the callback to include some specific value too, then add the `state` parameter.

The `options` in `function(options)` can be set when calling `passport.authenticate`:

```
router.get('/auth', passport.authenticate('ihealth', {time: Date.now()}));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this time I managed to find a workaround. Maybe it will help someone with a similar problem.

For the solution I didn't use the well known modules such as `passport-oauth2` or `simple-oauth2`, but just the modules `querystring` for building the request URL and the module `request` for making the HTTP calls.

Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var qs = require('querystring');
var configAuth = require('../config/auth');

var authorization_url_site = configAuth.iHealthAuth.authorizationSite;
var authorization_url_params = {
    response_type : 'code',
    client_id: configAuth.iHealthAuth.clientID,
    redirect_uri: configAuth.iHealthAuth.callbackURL,
    APIName : configAuth.iHealthAuth.APIName
};
var authorization_uri = authorization_url_site + '?' + qs.stringify(authorization_url_params);

var token_url_site = configAuth.iHealthAuth.tokenSite;
var token_url_params = {
    grant_type : 'authorization_code',
    client_id: configAuth.iHealthAuth.clientID,
    client_secret: configAuth.iHealthAuth.clientSecret,
    redirect_uri: configAuth.iHealthAuth.callbackURL,
    code: req.query.code
};
var token_uri = token_url_site + '?' + qs.stringify(token_url_params);

// Initial page redirecting to the login page
router.route('/auth')
    .get(function (req, res) {
            res.redirect(authorization_uri);
    });

// Callback service parsing the authorization token and asking for the access token
router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {

        request(token_uri, function(err, response, body) {
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    var data = JSON.parse(body);
                    // save token to database or file
                    saveToken(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I feel that your original question has meanwhile been answered by balafi. Care to accept their answer instead? (You were so close when you asked your question!)